# C++ correct memory release without information about allocation

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

This might sound like a silly question, but I couldn't find information on how to properly release memory in this case:

Assume there is a function returning a `double*` (there is no other information available about this function). Assume further the following use case:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    double *ptr = new double[3];

    /// do something with ptr, e.g., print

    // delete[] ptr;
}
```

How does one correctly release memory in this case, since a `delete[] ptr;` placed in the comment above causes a backtrace (why?)?

Many thanks!

Comment: The problem is with the code `/// do something with ptr, e.g., print` which clearly corrupts the heap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing

```
double *ptr = new double[3];

delete[] ptr;
```

is quite right. So your problem must reside somewhere else. I can recommend using a debugger to check what's going on, and if you're on a linux system I would recommend trying valgrind/helgrind - it's pretty nice

Answer (score 4):

> there is no other information available about this function

Then you can't know how to release the memory. Look at the function's source code if you have it, otherwise contact its author or use a debugging tool to find out how it allocates its memory. A raw pointer simply doesn't carry the necessary information to know how to deallocate it.

As for your second, unrelated case, the `delete[]` is correct so the problem must be in the "`do something`" part (assuming you didn't perform tricks such as `new` overloading).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 
I found the missing link in my train of thought and, digging more in the documentation of the API I'm looking into, I found the implementation of the function with a void return type and an out parameter double[3].